# how to use XML to make transaction in Using the Accept.js Payment Nonce

Tags: javascript, transactions, authorize.net

http://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/acceptjs.html
Manual says:

Using the Accept.js Payment Nonce to Charge a Credit Card
On your server you can call the Authorize.Net API just like you would if using actual credit card information. Simply replace the credit card element with the opaque data element.
For example:

```
    <createTransactionRequest xmlns="AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd">
       <merchantAuthentication>
         <name>yours</name>
         <transactionKey>yours</transactionKey>
       </merchantAuthentication>
       <transactionRequest>
          <transactionType>authCaptureTransaction</transactionType>
          <amount>75.00</amount>
          <payment>
             <opaqueData>
                <dataDescriptor>COMMON.ACCEPT.INAPP.PAYMENT</dataDescriptor>
                <dataValue>nonce_here</dataValue >
             </opaqueData>
          </payment>
       </transactionRequest>
   </createTransactionRequest>
```

But I don't understand how to put this XML into secureData = {}, authData = {}, cardData = {} objects.

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Did you include the Accept.js library on your page and then send the card details using the library to obtain the nonce?  

   ` <button type="submit" onclick="sendPaymentDataToAnet()">Pay</button>`

Comment: Yes I added it.

Comment: The flow is is to send the data after they click the send button, wait for the nonce in the return and then populate the XML request and submit for processing.